# CSRF verification from tcp socket

Tags: django, sockets, tcp

I have a django website running in my localhost. And I am to access the website through a tcp socket and post some data to the server.

I have succeeded in accessing the website but I am not able to post any data to the server due to csrf verification.

What I have done is, on the response I obtain from the server, I take out the csrf token and store it in a string and later post it through a post request. But I am getting csrf verification failed error.

How can I accomplish my task of posting data through tcp socket?

my code is as follows:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <boost/asio.hpp>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <ostream>

    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    void getresponse(std::string request, boost::asio::streambuf& response, tcp::socket& socket);

    int main()
    {
        std::string hostName = "localhost";
        std::string serviceName = "http";

        try
        {
            boost::asio::io_service io_service;

            // get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name
            tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
            tcp::resolver::query query(hostName, serviceName);
            tcp::resolver::iterator endpt_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
            tcp::resolver::iterator end;

            // try each endpoint until we successfully establish a connection
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            //tcp::socket socket1(io_service);
            boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

            while (error && endpt_iterator != end)
            {
                socket.close();
                //socket1.close();
                socket.connect(*endpt_iterator++, error);
                //socket1.connect(*endpt_iterator++, error);
            }
            if (error) 
            {
                std::cout << "Error connecting.. \n";
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }

            // we secify "Connection:close" header and thus the server closes after the response has been send.
            //   this will allow us to treat all data up untill the EOF as the content

            //boost::asio::streambuf request;
            //std::ostream request_stream(&request);
            std::string requeststr = "GET ";
            requeststr+="/ HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: bibek\r\nHost: localhost\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";

            boost::asio::streambuf response;

            std::string responseString, code;


            getresponse(requeststr, response, socket);

            std::istream response_stream(&response);


            while(!std::getline(response_stream, responseString).eof())
            {
                //std::cout << responseString << std::endl;
                if(responseString.find("csrfmiddlewaretoken")!=std::string::npos)
                {
                    // this one is for finding the value of csrf token
                    int pos1 = responseString.find("value");    
                    code = responseString.substr(pos1);
                    pos1 = code.find("\'");
                    code = code.substr(pos1+1);
                    pos1 = code.find("\'");
                    code = code.substr(0,pos1);
                    std::cout << code << std::endl;
                }
            }


            requeststr = "POST ";
            requeststr+="/ HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: bibek\r\nHost: localhost\r\nAccept: text/html\r\n";
            requeststr+= "Content-Type: application/x-www.form-urlencoded\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";
            requeststr+="&csrfmiddlewaretoken="+code+"name=bibek&email=pandey&comment=thisisnice";


            boost::asio::streambuf response1;
            getresponse(requeststr, response1, socket);
            std::istream response_stream1(&response1);
            while(!std::getline(response_stream1, responseString).eof())
            {
                std::cout << responseString << std::endl;
            }

                    // read until EOF, witing data to output as we go.
            while (boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
                std::cout << &response;

            if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                std::cout << "Error!!!!\n";
                throw boost::system::system_error(error);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception & e)
        {
            std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void getresponse(std::string requeststr, boost::asio::streambuf& response, tcp::socket& socket) 
    {
            char * testchar  = new char[requeststr.length() + 1];
            strcpy(testchar, requeststr.c_str());
            // send the request
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(testchar, requeststr.length()+1));

            // read the response until the end.
            boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "</html>");
    }
```

Here, first time I get response from the server and I can find out the csrf token. But, next time I send a Post(or Get) request, I get end of file exception though the connection is meant to be kept alive. I want to post the csrf token in the next request.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? It could be something simple, like you're sending the csrftoken back with the wrong name

Comment: I added a sample code.

Comment: I'm not an expert but your code seems sensible enough. Have you double checked that the code to extract the CSRF token is working properly? If it is then you'll have to go into the Django code to make sure that the received form data is what you expect it to me. You can do that by putting a [pdb.set_trace()](http://pymotw.com/2/pdb/#from-within-your-program) statement into the view code in your `django` installation